# Anime with ''aliens'' that steal the girl and old man and turn them into some freaks

Tags: story-identification, anime

I today remember one scene i totally forget about.  I watched it long long ago at 90s on tv.  Just once.

It have to be anime (but I'm not so sure is it japan anime) from early 90s or late 80s.
Cant say is it English language, or some other because i don't remember any talking/chat from that scene(s).

Its about anime where i think ''aliens'' steal a girl (by famous horizontal vacuum lights) and enchant her into cyborg in some glass tube.  I remember that she have one robotic arm or leg.  Maybe even both.
Somewhere in that scene is mixed and one old man same to be stolen by same way and enchanted like - not sure into what(cant remember).  Both are in those horizontal glass tubes, mad and ready to fight each other.

Comment: Not Sure, but resembles with this [post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180081/1995-2004ish-anime-dealing-with-kidnapped-trapped-girl-was-aired-on-mainstrea)

Comment: By question it sound similar.  But hard that this could be some early 00s. And same with answers it doesn't match.

Comment: Oh, okay! The answer with vacuum tube sounded similar to your post, that's why..